# Samba AD Groups different permissions to same share

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba

I am trying to configure a samba shares using samba4 version on Linux machine (which is joined to AD DOmain). My question is is there any way to configure two different AD Groups different access to the same share?

I have two shares:
1) /var/share1
2) /var/share2

Here is the configuration for the shares in /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[share1]
    comment = Share1 Folder
    path = /var/share1
    create mask = 0770
    directory mask = 0770
    read only = No
    valid users = @Oracle-Unix-Admin, @Oracle-Unix-Support
[share2]
    comment = Share2 Folder
    path = /var/share2
    create mask = 0770
    directory mask = 0770
    read only = No
    valid users = @Oracle-Unix-Admin, @Oracle-Unix-Support
```

I can login successfully with the AD Users which belong in these two groups, but the point is that both groups have the same permissions to the shares, and i need only the Oracle-Unix-Admin group to have full acess, and the Oracle-Unix-Support to have only read acces? Am i missing something in the configuration? How can i achieve such a behavior? Thank in advance.

Comment: I think this is typically solved by file/directory ownership on the underlying data, not as a configuration of samba.